ASP.NET MVC Kendo Grid throw Exception when collapse group with aggregation
I have grid for showing data from database. It has grouping and now I add one aggregate function - Sum on double field.
And its works good. I can group fields in my Grid and it apply Sum on field.
But when I try to open group, after grouping - I get error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasSubgroups')
at init.groupCount (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
at init._calculateGroupsTotal (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
at init.collapseGroup (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
at t._groupableClickHandler.t._groupableClickHandler (kendo.all.js:313050:21)
at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3:12445)
at r.handle (jquery.min.js:3:9174)

And I don't know what to do. I use Telerik demo as example and did everything like it. I also see, that someone from Telerik support team see this error and say its bug, but I don't see any solution.
This is my grid:
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DTRows>()
            .Name("newMainGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.FileName).Title("Имя файла").Width("200px").HideOnGroup(false);
                columns.Bound(c => c.Summa).Title("Стоимость").Width("100px").HideOnGroup(false)
                    .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Сумма1 : #=sum#")
                    .ClientGroupHeaderColumnTemplate("Сумма2 : #=sum#");
            })
            .Groupable()
            .Pageable()
            .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(600))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Aggregates(aggregates =>
                {
                    aggregates.Add(p => p.Summa).Sum();
                })
                .GroupPaging(true)
                .Read(read => read.Action("dt_read", "Home"))
                .PageSize(100)
            )
        )

What do I do wrong? Can it be fixed by my hand, or there is other solution to use group and aggregate in Kendo Grid?

Maybe this is related to the problem you have? Check your version and try the one after the fix in the linked issue.
